# find argmin of 3 vectors in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have three vectors 
`a = np.arange(3)`
`b = np.arange(2,-1,-1)`
`c = np.ones((3,))`
 and their minimum values element-wise via
 `np.minimum(a, b, c)`
which is: `m = [0. 1. 0.]`
I want to find from which array these values came, in my example I want input like:
`[0. x. 1.]` because first element in `m` came from `a` and last element in `m` came from `b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [argmin](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) method with the `axis` argument:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(3)
>>> b = np.arange(2,-1,-1)
>>> c = np.ones((3,))
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2])
>>> b
array([2, 1, 0])
>>> c
array([1., 1., 1.])
>>> all = np.stack([a, b, c])
>>> all
array([[0., 1., 2.],
       [2., 1., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
>>> all.min(axis=0)
array([0., 1., 0.])
>>> all.argmin(axis=0)
array([0, 0, 1])
```